# Getting error when converting multipage fillable PDF to html form using Abcpdf

Tags: html, pdf, abcpdf

The exception thrown was " at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10.Doc.Save(String path)
   at GetHtmlFromUploadedPdfDocument(Nullable`1 pageNumber) in....." .
The uploaded pdffile contains barcodes and fillable fext fields .

Below is the code i used to convert pdf to html.

```
            var filePaths= HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PDF//");           
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePaths);              
            doc.Read(bytes);
            if (pageNumber > 0)
            {
                doc.PageNumber = pageNumber.Value;
                doc.RemapPages(pageNumber.ToString());
            }
            var pdfFile = "sample";
            var htmlPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/HTML/" + pdfFile + ".html");
            doc.Encryption.CanChange = false;
            doc.Encryption.CanEdit = false;
            doc.Encryption.CanAssemble = false;
            doc.Encryption.CanExtract = false;
            doc.Encryption.CanFillForms = false;
            doc.Save(htmlPath);
            content = File.ReadAllText(htmlPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post. But i faced similar issue.
I solved it eventually, it might help others.

In my case, folder under which I was saving the file was missing proper permission.

Please perform following task:

- Right click on root folder where you are trying to save file.
- Select Properties. Uncheck Read-only in attributes section.
- Go to Security Tab. Select Edit > Add.
- Key in "Everyone" in text box. Then Check Names > Ok.
- Give "Everyone" Read, Write and Modify permission.